# Which to use or two set of results on Azure APIVersion

Tags: api, azure, azure-web-app-service, api-versioning

Scenario: To List WebApps under a resourcegroup name.

> ### Attempt Approach :

```
$WebAppApiVersion = "2015-08-01"
$MyResourceGroup = 'gurustorageRG'
Function saymyWebApps($ResourceGroupName)
 {
   Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $myResourceType -ApiVersion $WebAppApiVersion
 }

` saymyWebApps $MyResourceGroup
```

> ### Output
>
> Find-AzureRmResource : InvalidApiVersionParameter : The api-version '2015-08-01' is invalid. The supported versions are '2017-08-01,2
>   017-06-01,2017-05-10,2017-05-01,2017-03-01,2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-
>   04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.
>   At line:24 char:5
>   +     Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Resou ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Find-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidApiVersionParameter,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceMan

So, I picked 2017-08-01 from the listed error output for my webapiversion parameter and re-attempted, strangely it works listing the webapps created today or I assume at this point could list any app setup post 2017-08-01 ONLY.

> Question 1: Does this mean, I would have to pull out available -apiversion and iterate through them to build entire webapp list under a resource group?
>
> Attempted to see -apiversion but the output appears not complete or not matching with error thrown above as in Output block.

Snippet used to list the API Version:

```
Function GetAPIVersions()
 {
 ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).ApiVersions
}

GetAPIVersions
```

> ### Output
>
> 2016-08-01
>
> 2016-03-01
>
> 2015-08-01-preview
>
> 2015-08-01
>
> 2015-07-01
>
> 2015-06-01
>
> 2015-05-01
>
> 2015-04-01
>
> 2015-02-01
>
> 2014-11-01
>
> 2014-06-01
>
> 2014-04-01-preview
>
> 2014-04-01

The above result is on successful execution of apiversion listing snippet.

> Question 2: Why is the apiversion listing above not showing the api-versions list as shown in the error output of initial attempt approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use fiddler to catch the execution of `Find-AzureRmResource`,it uses the [List Resource API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/Resources/List). We could find that the parameter `-ApiVersion` stands for **[list resource api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/Resources/List) version**. **It is not related to what resource type** we want to find.

> Question 2: Why is the apiversion listing above not showing the api-versions list as shown in the error output of initial attempt approach?

You mentioned **list the API Version** for **Microsoft.Web** , the output api version could be used for operating WebApp,for instance, [create or update azure webApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate).

So **-ApiVersion** and **list API version** are different.

**In summary:**

if we want to  use **Find-AzureRmResource** command,we need to use the api versions that mentioned in the error info.

If we want to find the operation sepicial resource type resource api version, we could use you mentioned list api way.

Comment: Interesting! Ok, so that is why the listings differ. Thanks!